# Bootstrap 3.3.5 - Change Table Row Background Colour for 'Info' Class on a single page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to change the background colour for table rows that have the 'info' default class assigned on a single page. I've added the following CSS:

```css
.table tbody>tr.info {
  background-color: #24e5d2 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Definition</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="info">
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but the table row colour is not changing from the default blue shade for the info class not the new custom colour.

Comment: `tr` directly does not take css properties like `margin` `padding` etc. so you have to target td on basis of tr. check below answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will change:

```css
.table tbody>tr.info td{
  background-color: #24e5d2 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Definition</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="info">
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```